# Redirecting from submission form to thank you page in PHP

Tags: php

I am in the process of changing from recaptcha to a honey pot to avoid spam on my site.  www.dentistheadhunter.com.  I am using www.dentistheadhunter.com/indexpot.php for my trial run and when I submit my form, the process form is working in inputting into my database and sending me an email, but the Thank you form redirect is not working and the process form (http://www.dentistheadhunter.com/resumefrontpot2.php) just ends in a blank page instead of redirecting to my thank_you.php page.

I have read up on previous questions and removed any white space before the starting php tag and that did not solve the problem.

Here is my code

```
<?php
require("includes/dbconnect/mob_db.php");
$robotest = $_POST['robotest'];
if($robotest)
echo "Thank you for your inquiry Robot.";
$cand_sql = 'INSERT INTO dent_leads (first_name,last_name,disc_id,city,state,zip,area_code,phone,email,location,setting,experience,timestamp,source,notes,resume_path) VALUES ("' . $_POST['first_name'] . '","' . $_POST['last_name'] . '","' . $_POST['disc'] . '","' . $_POST['city'] . '","' . $_POST['state'] . '","' . $_POST['zip'] . '","' . $_POST['area_code'] . '","' . $_POST['phone1'] . $_POST['phone2'] . '","' . $_POST['email'] .  '","' . $_POST['location'] . '","' . $_POST['setting'] .'","' . $_POST['experience'] .'","' . time() . '","DentistHeadHunterFP.com","' . $_POST['comments'] . '","' . $target_path .'")';
$cand_res = mysql_query($cand_sql,$leads_db);
if(is_array($_POST['license'])){
    foreach($_POST['license'] as $lic_state){
        if($lic_state != ''){
            $licensed .= ',("' . $dent_id . '","' . $lic_state . '")';
        }
    }
    if(isset($licensed)){
        $lic_sql = 'INSERT INTO dent_lic (dent_id,state) VALUES ' . ltrim($licensed,',');
        $lic_res = mysql_query($lic_sql,$leads_db);
    }
} 

$msg  .= 'Name: ' . $_POST['first_name'] . ' ' . $_POST['last_name'] . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'Discipline: ' . $_POST['disc']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'City: ' . $_POST['city']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'State: ' . $_POST['state']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'Zip: ' . $_POST['zip']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'Phone: ' . $_POST['area_code'] . '-' . $_POST['phone1'] . '-' . $_POST['phone2'] . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'Experience: ' . $_POST['experience'] . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'Lead Source: First page ' . $_POST[''] . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'Settings: ' . $_POST['setting']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= ' ' . $_POST['']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'Location: ' . $_POST['location']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= ' ' . $_POST['']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'First Page Comments: ' . $_POST['comments'] . '<br />' . "\r\n";

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers  .= 'Return-Path: <dentistjobs@dentistheadhunter.com> ' . "\r\n";
    $headers  .= 'From: Dentist Head Hunter Candidate <dentistjobs@dentistheadhunter.com> ' . "\r\n";
    $headers  .= 'Reply-To: Dentist Head Hunter Candidate <dentistjobs@dentistheadhunter.com> ' . "\r\n";
    $headers  .= 'Bcc: Dentist Head Hunter Candidate <dentistjobs@dentistheadhunter.com> ' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    mail('dentistjobs@dentistheadhunter.com','NEW HEADHUNTER LEAD',$msg,$headers);
    header( 'Location: http://www.dentistheadhunter.com/thank_you.php' ) ;
```

?>

Comment: Ends in a blank page because there is an error. Check your logs.

Comment: A blank page when output is expected in PHP means _look in the error log_.  _Always_ when developing code, display all errors on screen.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the script...

Comment: Well, something that smells wrong with the code would be the `$_POST['']`'s that you have in your `$msg`

Comment: You shouldn't just change from recaptcha to honeypot, imho you should throw that stuff away, grab a book about modern web development in PHP, switch to a framework and start enjoying your life. ;-) Just some hints: you're open to SQL injections, still using `mysql_*` functions, relying on `mail()`, …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are `echo` message before `header()`

If you want to echo the message, then write

```
ob_start();
echo "Thank you for your inquiry Robot.";
header('Location:http://www.dentistheadhunter.com/thank_you.php');
ob_end_flush();
```